# mongoose database.find result return with nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, callback, mongodb-query

I am trying to query using using mongoDB and send the result from nodejs to angularJs.

**NodeJS Code**

```
app.get('/mfsearch/:aId/:categ/:type', function(req, res, next) {
    var aId = parseInt(req.params.aId);
    var categ = req.params.categ;
    var type = req.params.type;
    console.log(aId+','+categ+','+type);
    MHistory.find({
        $and : [{schemeCategory :categ},{schemeType:type},{amcNumber : aId},{schemeStatus : 'Active'}]
    }, function(err, fund) {
        if (err) {
            return next(err);
        }
        console.log(fund);
        res.json(fund);
    });
});
```

I am getting null as the fund value.

I searched through few forums and changed code as below.

```
var mfResult = function(categ1,type1,aId1){
    console.log(aId1+','+categ1+','+type1); 
    MHistory.find({
    $and : [{schemeCategory :categ1},{schemeType:type1},{amcNumber : aId1},{schemeStatus : 'Active'}]
}).exec(function(err, fund) {
    if (err) {
        return next(err);
    }
    console.log(fund);
    return fund;
});
};

app.get('/mfsearch/:aId/:categ/:type', function(req, res, next) {
    var amcId = parseInt(req.params.aId);
    var categ = req.params.categ;
    var type = req.params.type;
    console.log(aId+','+categ+','+type); 
    res.json(mfResult(categ,type,aId));
});
```

Query seems to be fine as I am getting the result from the same query using Robo 3T.

Comment: Your first code block is closest.  Is your aId variable supposed to be a MongoDb _id?  As you have it, it is string.

Comment: No,aId is different from mongoDB _id.It is product id.

Comment: Still unclear.  What is the variable type of your amcNumber field?  Is it string?

Comment: first try with the simple query. like  MHistory.find({}, function(err, fund) {})

Comment: @JeffMatthews Data type is integer. I am using parseInt(req.params.aId).

Comment: Your 1st code looks good.  Have you tried starting with a single condition to see if that works, and if so, adding 1 new condition at a time?  Maybe 1 of them is failing, and you can isolate it.  I do see your colons (:) are not aligned like "this: that".